# Block Visibility Settings not working in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming, drupal-blocks

Now for a specific block, I wanted it to be visible only on the front page. So I edited the block visibility settings for specific pages and made it <front>.

But the block is showing up in all the page. I have also tried other options like roles. In all the cases the desired result is not realized and I keep getting the blocks visible in all the pages for all the roles.

A background of situation: I had a theme, using which I have developed a sub-theme. Has anybody encountered something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Block visibility is per-theme so make sure that you are setting the visibility for the intended theme. Try also setting the block visibility for the theme and/or the subtheme, so you can determine if it has to do with it.